# How send dynamic data from contentscript.js to background.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a simple Google chrome extension. But when I try to send some dynamic data from contentscript.js to background.html, I get no result.
There is no problem with sending static data.

here is the **background.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
      <script>
      chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
                            alert(request.text);
                           });
      </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

and here is the **conentscript.js** with static data that works **fine**:

```
var req = {"text": "salam"};
chrome.extension.sendRequest(req);
```

and this is **contentscript.js** that **doesn't work**:

```
var txt = getSelectedText();
var req = {"text": txt};
chrome.extension.sendRequest(req);
```

any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an object via request you don't pass a reference to it, as with  regular functions. This object is actually getting serialized into a string before a request, passed as a string, and then assembled back from a string in a background page (that's why you can't pass anything in a request that cannot be serialized). All references are lost in the process.

You probably would need to rethink your extension architecture to accommodate this.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer. I used String(txt) to solve the problem, because "txt" String, there is no problem on code execution.